# String replace: multiple replace is not working in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, str-replace

I have a string and some text (name attr) should be replaced with dynamic text. For example 
`options[team_member][0][name]` will be replaced with `options[team_member][1][name]`.

What far i did:

```
    var current = 1;

    var block = jQuery('#contents').html();
    var replace_str = 'options[team_member]['+(current-1)+']';
    var replace_with = 'options[team_member]['+(current)+']';

    /* replace only first match */
    var rep_block = block.replace(replace_str,replace_with);

    /* replace nothing */
    // var rep_block = block.replace(/replace_str/g,replace_with);

    /* replace nothing */
    // var rep_block = block.replace(/(replace_str)/g,replace_with);

    alert(rep_block);
```

Please check full code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/itskawsar/2QFUw/)

I cannot find the way how can i solve this. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Operating on a HTML string is the wrong solution.

Comment: ok. i want to add a html block with some inputs with some dynamic name. How can i make it? Do you like to share your idea please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please replace

```
var rep_block = block.replace(replace_str,replace_with);
```

with

```
var rep_block = block.split(replace_str).join(replace_with);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use global replace with "g" flag: /reg_ex_here/g or new RegExp(exp, 'g')

```
var string = 'bla bla bla';
string.replace(/bla/g, 'ok'); // -> ok ok ok
string.replace(new RegExp('bla', 'g'), 'ok'); // -> ok ok ok
```

In your code:

```
var replace_str = 'options\\[team_member\\]\\['+(current-1)+'\\]';
rep_block = block.replace(new RegExp(replace_str, 'g'), replace_with);
```

Comment: please check jsFiddle first.
`var rep_block = block.replace(/replace_str/g,replace_with);` // replace nothing

Comment: oh, string to replace include brackets... i updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2QFUw/6/ but this is not good solution. Use split + join solution by @Hitesh

Comment: Please update your answer anyway to use a properly escaped `replace_str`. Right now the second part is plain wrong.